# BTE to change/update the "Valid From" and "Valid to" dates in IDENTIFICATION tab of transaction code BP

Tags: abap, sap-erp

Any idea which BTE will be triggered to change/update the fields in the 'Identification tab' of transaction BP?

I can already validate the entries entered in the identification tab by creating FM under BUP520 (Identification Numbers) and using FMs BUP_BUPA_BUT100_GET and BUP_BUPA_BUT0ID_GET to retrieve identification numbers entered.

But say for example, if Valid From/To date is blank, I would like to automatically fill the fields with my own values: Valid From (first day of the current month), Valid to (12/31/9999).

Thank you.
Regards,
Kath